# WPF loading image from internet

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image, webclient

Hey all i am trying to find a way to load an image via the WebClient using a WFP window.... The code below loads just fine when i am using a normal Windows Form:

```
Dim wc As New Net.WebClient

picNextTopic1.Image = Image.FromStream(wc.OpenRead(theAPI.ImgURL(2).Replace("{width}", "50").Replace("{height}", "50")))
```

However, this doesnt seem to work for WPF???

The WPF seems to use a **.source** for images? How can i convert that code above in order to use it with a WPF window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is not Windows Forms. You need to build WPF applications completely different. Properties, INotifyPropertyChanged etc.

But to your problem:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
Dim bytes = wc.DownloadData("http://....")
Dim ms = New MemoryStream(bytes)
Dim img = New BitmapImage()

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
img.BeginInit()
img.StreamSource = ms
img.EndInit()

picNextTopic1.Source = img
```

Comment: Where in all that code does it place the image into the image called **picNextTopic1**?

Comment: You have to add this part of code yourself. It is just initialising it ;) That is just a general example!